# Method on how to find the inverse of this triangular matrix $(n,n)$

Tags: matrices, inverse

Let $n\in\mathbb N^*$, Find the Inverse  of the triangular matrix $L$ :

$$L=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \\
0 & 2 & 1 &  & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & 3 & \ddots & \vdots \\
\vdots &  & \ddots & \ddots & 1\\
0 & \cdots & \cdots & 0 & n\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

Previously, I was able to quickly determine the inverses of matrices.

Now I'm trying to re-do this one, but I'm stuck. Could someone remind me of some good ways to solve such matrix?

Comment: You may try on small $n$ to find a pattern. It's a triangular matrix, inversion is easy by backsubstitution. Once you have the pattern, prove it directly.

Comment: Oh yes. In this way, it is fairly easy to find an inverse ! Thanks !